# Visual studio code python break point never works with Attach to Python Functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Visual studio code python break point never works with "Attach to Python Functions" but works fine with "Python: Current File". I have tried below steps nothing works

1. Stop VS Code auto update
2. Install python extension, install another version...
3. Uninstall/install VS Code..
4. Uninstall/install extensions..
5. "justMyCode": false
6. "justMyCode": true and remove "stopOnEntry": true from launch.json file...
7. "justMyCode": false,"stopOnEntry": true...
8. Remove cache, pip cache, temp files..
9. Remove virtual environment and add virtual env again...

Below are the VS Code details:
Version: 1.69.1 (user setup)
Commit: b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a
Date: 2022-07-12T08:21:24.514Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Below is my launch.json file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "stopOnEntry": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9091,
        "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
```

Comment: if you don't start a debugger on port 9091 there is nothing to attach to, why is it called `Attach to Python Functions` and not `Attach to Python Process`

Comment: Debugger is started on port 9091 already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding extensions.json, tasks.json, settings.json file along with launch.json file in .vscode folder